# CS1955 C# Non-invocable member 'Match.Date' cannot be used like a method. I'm getting an error like this,can someone help me please.

Tags: c#, date

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Matches
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            MatchesContext db = new MatchesContext();
            Match match = new Match();
            match.M_ID = 4;
            string sdate = "2015-03-10";
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(sdate);
            match.Date(sdate);
            match.Team1 = "Kolkata";
            match.Team2 = "Mumbai";
            match.Umpire = "Benson";
            db.Matches.Add(match);
            db.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("object is created");
            Console.ReadKey();
        } 
    }
}
```

Non-invocable member 'Match.Date' cannot be used like a method.This is the error i'm getting.Can someone please help me

Answer (score 0):

It seems `Date` is a property, not a method. If you want to assign a value to it, use

```
match.Date = dt;
```

Comment: You were spot on.Thank you very much!